# Flask-Login user is apparently anonymous

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I have the following view:

```
@app.route('/write-blog-post', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@app.route('/<userID>/write-blog-post', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def writePost(userID=None):

    if not current_user.is_anonymous() and userID != None:
        if current_user.id == int(userID):
            ...
    ...
```

For some reason, when a user is logged in using Flask login so `if not current_user.is_anonymous()` is `True` and they go to the URL with the userID, I receive an error stating that:

```
`AttributeError: 'AnonymousUserMixin' object has no attribute 'id'`
```

I user `current_user.id` on other views and it works successfully. The only thing I think that can bring about the error is the multiple URLs for the view which possibly interfere with something.

The odd thing is that even when the user passes both if statements, the function still continues as normal.

What could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Is that a copy-paste from your flask script? I don't understand how `<write-blog-post>` in the second line can have `<>` brackets.

Comment: A couple of unrelated changes: you can make `userID` always be an `int` with `<int:userID>` in the route and you should check `None` for identity (`userID is not None`) rather than equality.

Comment: @Robᵩ that was a typing error in the question now fixed, it isn't like that in the actual code.

Comment: @dirn thanks for the pointers.

Comment: Do you implement is_anonymous in your user class, or do you inherit from the mixin? If you do implement it, do you implement it as a method or as a property? Because when I run the code you've posted, I get this error: `File "/tmp/f/app.py", line 56, in writePost`
`if not current_user.is_anonymous() and userID != None:`
`TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable`.